# Switch and router configuration

Tags: networking, router, vpn, vlan, pfsense

I have a mini PC with dual NICs that I want to use for a pfSense router. At the moment there is a regular router with four LAN ports there. Two of these go to switches - a managed PoE one for a bunch of APs and a big dumb one for ports in the house.

If I use the mini PC box, I will only have one LAN port.

What would be best practice here? Would it matter which of the switches is first in the chain?

I do plan on using a VLAN with VPN in this network, which would include one of the APs and two wired PCs.

Comment: Probably want Dumbo last

Comment: So i figured. I also am left with a relatively powerful five port Edgerouter X. Any reason to add it to the network? Maybe as a managed switch that then goes to the two other switches? To offload some processing from the switch running the wifi network?

Answer (score 0):

> I do plan on using a VLAN with VPN in this network, which would include one of the APs and two wired PCs.

Ideally, then, you should arrange the switches such that VLAN-tagged frames never have to go through an unmanaged switch that's incapable of VLAN filtering. This applies not just to the APs but also to the wired PCs that need to be in a non-default VLAN – it's best if they are connected to the managed switch which tags/untags the VLAN for them, and if the managed switch is then connected directly to the router.

(This assumes the managed switch has enough capacity for the other switch to chain off it – i.e. it's not some old 100 Mbps-only switch.)

An unmanaged switch can still *forward* VLAN-tagged packets but does so indiscriminately (all hosts will see them and this can often cause problems with Windows in particular, as it'll pick up tagged packets as if they were untagged).

Comment: I have the Ubiquiti EdgeSwitch 8, which has two free ports and now a spare Edgerouter with its five ports (I understand it can be converted into a managed switch). So I should have pfSense -> Edgerouter in switch mode -> PCs/ EdgeSwitch/ dumb switch? This way the VLAN would be always on managed switches. Thanks for the advice btw!

Comment: It [looks like](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/217990978-EdgeRouter-Configure-an-EdgeRouter-as-a-Layer-2-Switch) some EdgeRouter models have hardware switching capability (with VLAN support), but not all of them do. (There's one exception to "VLAN always on managed switches" – if you have a bunch of APs or other VLAN-aware devices and _all_ of them want the exact same tagged VLANs, then you _could_ put them on a non-VLAN-aware PoE switch at the end.)

Comment: I only have the one managed PoE switch, but the EdgeRouter ERX definitely can be a managed switch, just checked and theres a wizard in the GUI.